# How can one implement an array of functions on C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I am trying to implement an interpreter. I'd love to go with GCC first class labels to make it threaded code, but I should hold on to a standard this time, so naturally I am left with function table. So, I'm doing this:

```
unsigned short int FUN_TABLE[MAX_FUN] (void*);
```

And I want to fill it with functions, each getting pointer to its operands, doing its part, returning length of the whole instruction in memory to a dispatcher.

The thing is, I can't even compile it due to the following error: `declaration of FUN_TABLE as array of functions`. Considering it is exactly what I am trying to achieve, why is this an error, why should I pay it attention, and if I shouldn't, how to suppress it in elegant and standardized manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an array of function pointers like this (pseudocode):

```
int (*funcArr2[10])(param, param, ...) = {NULL};
```

However, you should be aware that this means that all these functions have the same set of arguments. You can not declare an array with function pointers to totall different functions with regard to their signature.

Comment: In practice, you can actually declare an array of function pointers with different signatures, as long as the have the same size and use the same calling convention. But formally, casting between function pointers of different types is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

GCC is telling you: "there is no such thing as an array of functions".

> Considering it is exactly what I am trying to achieve, why is this an error, why should I pay it attention

Because you are trying to achieve something that does not exist in the C language. But instead, you can achieve the desired functionality through an array of function pointers.

The syntax of declaring a function pointer is

```
return_type (*func_ptr_name)(parameters)
```

and the syntax for declaring an array of function pointers is

```
return_type (*func_ptr_name[n])(parameters)
```

Since that syntax is quite obscure, you will not want to use it. The solution is to use typedefs:

```
typedef unsigned short (*func_table_t)(void*);

// declare an array of function pointers, using readable syntax:
func_table_t func_table [MAX_FUNC] =
{
  &some_function,
  &some_other_function,
  ...
};
```

Comment: +1. Micro-nit: there's no need to use `&` to take the address of a function.

Comment: @unwind I know, but I consider it good practice to make your intention clear. Same goes when executing a function through a function pointer, you can type `*ptr()` or `ptr()`, they are equivalent, but the former might be more readable, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of functions aren't legal. Your easiest work around would be an array of **pointers** to functions -- but this implies that each function being pointed to from the array has the same signature.